# Using Babel's `sourceRoot` Doesn't Affect Imports

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

Currently I can do:

```
require('./frontend/src/components/SomeComponent');
```

But if I set the following in my `webpack.config.js`:

```
resolve: {
    root: path.resolve('frontend', 'src')
}
```

I can instead do:

```
require('components/SomeComponent');
```

The problem is, when I don't use Webpack (eg. in a test environment) all of my imports break.  According to the Babel docs, the `sourceRoot` property sets the "root from which all sources are relative."  This made me think I could add the following to my `.babelrc` to fix my imports:

```
"sourceRoot": "frontend/src"
```

... but no such luck.  When I do `require('components/SomeComponent');` in `babel-node` it fails.  When I just use Babel to transpile the file, the `require` line is the same whether or not I set a `sourceRoot`.

So, my question is, is there any way (with or without `sourceRoot`) to simulate webpack's `resolve.root` in Babel?

P.S. I know there are several Babel plug-ins which address this problem, but all of the ones I've seen require you to add a `~` to the `require` path (which of course breaks imports in Webpack).

Answer (score 1):

Many project have webpack + babel, and in many projects you sometimes bypass webpack (as in your case - for tests).

In such cases, all the resolve aliases should live in babel.

There are plugins out there to allow one reading the configuration of the other (and similar plugins for eslint etc.).